# Pagination based on filtered results in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-rest-framework

I have a simple filtering in my get function which needs to be paginated. I tried different ways of solving this issue , but I am not able to figure out what exactly needs to be done. The following is my code

```
class UserInfoViewSets(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def UserInfo_post(self,request, format=None):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            serializer = UserInfoSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def UserInfo_get(self,request,user_token):  
        if request.method == 'GET':
            queryset = UserInfo.objects.filter(user_token=user_token)
            serializer = UserInfoSerializer(queryset,many=True)
```

I need to paginate the get results. I dont want to write a customized pagination class, but just set the parameter to limit the no of results per page. I have tried setting the following in the setting.py file

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 2,
}
```

In my views file , I added ListAPIView

```
class UserInfoListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    model = UserInfo
    serializer_class = UserInfoSerializer
    paginate_by_param = 'limit'
```

clearly I am overlooking some minor detail. I tried scouting thought the documentation. But it seems to be geared towards people who are well versed with django.

Comment: Any reason you are not using [ModelViewSet](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset)?

Comment: Well I dont know about it. I am newbie in this. Would love, if you could enlighten me.

Comment: Should do what you want, see the examples in the documentation.

Comment: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset  doesnt talk about pagination or setting page_limit or page_size . Unless , I am checking the wrong link.

Comment: `ModelViewSet` will use all the generic pagination settings you mentioned above and furthermore it will handle the post/get functionality you implemented yourself.

Comment: you can also use @api_view decorators for specific tasks.

Comment: An example would be much appreciated. Honestly, its not very clear from the docs.

Comment: I've added a code for explanation hope it'll help.

Answer (score 1):

That is what I do for pagination, filtering, ordering etc... First you need to `pip install django-filter` (https://github.com/alex/django-filter)

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {

    . . . 

    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'rest_framework.filters.DjangoFilterBackend',
    ),
    'PAGE_SIZE': 1000

    . . .

}
```

views.py

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'id'
    queryset = Users.objects.order_by('id')
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
    filter_backends = (SearchFilter, OrderingFilter)
    search_fields = ('^id', '^first_name', '^last_name', '^email', ^username',)
```

I am using AngularJS,

```
function getUserList(limit, pageNumber, search, ordering) {

    var def = $q.defer();
    offset = (pageNumber -1) * limit;
    $http.get(API_URL +
        '?limit=' +limit +
        '&offset=' + offset +
        '&search=' + search +
        '&ordering=' + ordering)

    .success(function(data){
        def.resolve(data);
    })
    .error(function(data){
        def.resolve(data);
    });

    return def.promise;
}
```

Example query:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/?limit=10&offset=0&search=%20&ordering=id
```

Comment: Use `django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend` instead of `rest_framework.filters.DjangoFilterBackend` because we using module `django_filter`, not from `rest_framework`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @umut and @prashant.  I am sharing my version plainly using DRF.  Hopefully, others new to drf will find this easier.

```
def Users_get(self,request,user_token): 
        if request.method == 'GET':
            queryset = Users.objects.filter(user_token=user_token)
            paginator = PageNumberPagination()
            result_page = paginator.paginate_queryset(queryset, request)
            serializer = UsersSerializer(result_page,many=True)
            return paginator.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```

This gave me response with next and previous url links.

Answer (score 0):

In code below entire viewset is designed GET POST PUT DELETE also your query regarding pagination over filtered query is also handled. 
Pagination is done using Paginator its a built-in in django

For docs cover most of the part go to [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/) for that. DRF docs can be confusing sometimes but django docs are finely descriptive and easy to implement

> views.py

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def product_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        products = Product.objects.all()
        product_make_up = Product.objects.filter(item_category__exact='Make Up')[:3]
        product_skincare = Product.objects.filter(item_category__exact='Skin Care')[:3]
        product_fragrance = Product.objects.filter(item_category__exact='Fragrance')[:3]
        product_personal_care = Product.objects.filter(item_category__exact='Personal Care')[:3]
        product_hair_care = Product.objects.filter(item_category__exact='Hair Care')[:3]
        product_item_category = QuerySetChain(product_make_up,
                                          product_skincare,
                                          product_fragrance,
                                          product_personal_care,
                                          product_hair_care)
        item_cates = request.query_params.get('item_category',None)
        if item_cates is not None:
             product = products.filter(item_category=item_cates)
             paginator = Paginator(product,5)
             page = request.query_params.get('page')
             product = paginator.page(page)
             try:
                 product = paginator.page(page)
             except PageNotAnInteger:
                 product = paginator.page(1)
             except EmptyPage:
                 product = pagintor.page(paginator.num_pages)
                 serializer = ProductSerializer(product, many=True)
    else:
        paginator = Paginator(product_item_category,15)
        page = request.query_params.get('page')
        product_item_category = paginator.page(page)
        try:
            product_item_category = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            product_item_category = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            product_item_category = pagintor.page(paginator.num_pages)
        serializer = ProductSerializer(product_item_category, many=True)    
    return Response(serializer.data)
elif request.method == 'POST':
    serializer = ProductSerializer( data=request.data)
    # data.encode("base64")
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        res_msg = {'Success_Message' : 'Successful','Success_Code' : 200}
        return Response(res_msg)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def product_detail(request, pk):
"""
Get, udpate, or delete a specific task
"""
    try:
        product = Product.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = ProductSerializer(product)
        return Response(serializer.data , status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = ProductSerializer(product, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(
            serilizer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        product.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Comment: DRF doenst play well with  Paginator fron django.

Comment: The code above is in DRF and it works perfectly fine their might be a problem with urls then